# Tikz-feynman not working that previously worked

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

The following code gives the weird result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-feynman}
\begin{document} 
\begin{equation}
        \begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]
            \begin{feynman}
                \vertex[dot] (c) {};
                \vertex[above left=of c] (k) {$i_3$};
                \vertex[below left=of c] (l) {$i_4$};
                \vertex[above right=of c] (j) {$i_2$};
                \vertex[below right=of c] (i) {$i_1$};
                \diagram*{
                    (k) --[fermion] (c)
                    (l) --[fermion] (c)
                    (c) --[fermion] (j)
                    (c) --[fermion] (i)
                };
            \end{feynman}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

One of the error message is:

> Package pgf Error: No shape named `{(c)} (l' is known. }

I am using LuaLaTeX. Surprisingly, when I ran the same code one year ago, it normally worked. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE starting by `\documentclass` and ending by `\end{document}`.

Comment: @SebGlav I modified the question.

Comment: Works fine for me, you may have to update your editor, or your LaTeX distribution. Try loading `tikz-feynman` with `\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}`.

Comment: Fails also for me, TeXLive2021 up-to-date to today (yes, running with lualatex). Smells like a bug. @SebGlav which is your system/version?

Comment: I tested it on Overleaf: works on TeXLive2018 and breaks on TeXLive2019, 20 and 21. Something changed in Ti*k*Z, I suppose. (The date on tikz-feyman is 2016, so I do not think it has changed. There is a github here: https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman)

Comment: I tried it with MikTeX (without LuaTeX) at work (can't get the version), and it rendered correctly, despite the warnings.

Comment: @Rmano Wow... I think that is the reason. One year ago, if I remember correctly, I tested with older version of tex, but not now. Thanks everybody for helpful comments.

Comment: @eigenvalue I think you should rise an issue there... https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/issues